# How does the velocity and acceleration of long length stick or rod varies according to its length?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

Let's say I have stick or rod of length $L$.

I am moving the stick using my hand and the motion is not circular or spherical. The motion may be oval or some other shape, because while moving the stick I may fold my hand so total length may vary.

If I know the acceleration $a_x$, $a_y$, $a_z$, angular velocity and linear velocity of the base $P$ of the stick from where I grab the stick. Is it possible to know the acceleration and velocity of stick at the end point $Q$, as shown in the following image
 [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TPN1.png)?

Comment: As you moved the stick it is likely that you are also rotating it. If this is the case you have to know how and factor this in.

Comment: ya right rotation will also happen and the angular velocity (wx, wy,wz) is know

Comment: Sounds like a use-case for [Euler-Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation). Easier to understand is the [inverted pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pendulum) example. An excellent read for an introduction to the energy-based approach is _Principles and Techniques of Vibrations_ by Leonard Meirovitch.

Comment: Is the motion is planar ? What do you mean the total length may be vary ?

Comment: means when moving the stick then the total = length of hand+length of stick but if hand is folded then the total length is decreased.